# FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. - Changed ASP.net Core Identity PK to int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've been working on this for the last 3 hours and haven't found a good resource or solution to this problem. I've followed the directions found in Microsoft's documentation to change my ASP.net Privatekey from a string to an int. Since then, I have been presented with the following error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

The app will not load past this method in the program.cs class:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

I have hit a roadblock and any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Asp.net Error Stack:

FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)

ArgumentException: 4c3ccce2-61cd-4315-9cf2-99933f6797ed is not a valid value for Int32. (Parameter 'value')
System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
int.Parse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(string value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)

Show raw exception details
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
ArgumentException: 4c3ccce2-61cd-4315-9cf2-99933f6797ed is not a valid value for Int32. (Parameter 'value')
System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(string text)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase<TUser, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>.ConvertIdFromString(string id)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim>.FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(string userId)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.ArgumentException: 4c3ccce2-61cd-4315-9cf2-99933f6797ed is not a valid value for Int32. (Parameter 'value')
---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase`5.ConvertIdFromString(String id) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.FindByIdAsync(String userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByIdAsync(String userId) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem may be that the login of your previous user may be completed when the `ID` is a `string`.

You now change it to int, so now it no longer knows what to do with the `string`.

I think the simplest solution is that you should delete the `cookie`, log out and log in again (`use int instead`).

Comment: Thank you, I was banging my head against the wall on this one.